# Adding custom http headers to every request of a SOAP service

Tags: java, web-services, http, soap, http-headers

I am using a JAX-WS SOAP Client to send custom http headers to the service as follows.

```
  Map<String, Object> request_map = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
  request_map.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
       "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL");
  Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<>();
  headers.put("username", Collections.singletonList("User1"));
  request_map.put(javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```

I am tracing the SOAP request on tomcat by setting the following system properties.

```
static {
       System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
      System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump",
          "true");
      System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
      System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
}
```

It logs the Http Request but does but the request does not contain the header.

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Mhh for me this looks ok. It should work. Have you checked the headers of the receiving side?